# Trying to make two SQL INSERT statements atomic in C# code

Tags: c#, sql, transactions, ssis, atomic

Below is the code I'm using in an SSIS script task. I am trying to make both inserts atomic as they deal with similar customers.

The first `.executeNonQuery()` works fine, locking the SQL table as it should.

The second `.executNonQuery()` throws an error:

> *ExecuteNonQuery requires the command to have a transaction when the
>   connection assigned to the command is in a pending local transaction. 
>   The Transaction property of the command has not been initialized.*

Code:

```
    ConnectionManager cm; 
    SqlTransaction sqlTrans;
    SqlConnection sqlConn;
    SqlCommand sqlComm;                                  
    cm = Dts.Connections["connectionManager"];

    try
    {
         //Set 'global' variables                                        
         SqlParameter agentID = new SqlParameter("@agentID", 1000018); //retrievedMessage.Substring(2, 10));//Primary key
         SqlParameter lastChangeOperator = new SqlParameter("@lastChangeOperator", "LVO");
         SqlParameter lastChangeDate = new SqlParameter("@lastChangeDate", DateTime.Now);
         SqlParameter controlId = new SqlParameter("@controlID", 1); //Hard-coded value for testing - CHANGE LATER

         //Set variables for Agent table
         SqlParameter entityType = new SqlParameter("@entityType", "P");//retrievedMessage.Substring(162, 1));
         SqlParameter fName = new SqlParameter("@fName", "test");//retrievedMessage.Substring(12, 25));
         SqlParameter lName = new SqlParameter("@lName", "test");//retrievedMessage.Substring(37, 35));
         SqlParameter suffix = new SqlParameter("@suffix", "test");//retrievedMessage.Substring(72, 10));
         SqlParameter corporateName = new SqlParameter("@corporateName", "Initech");//retrievedMessage.Substring(82, 80));

         //Insert record into Agent table
         sqlConn = (SqlConnection)cm.AcquireConnection(Dts.Transaction);
         sqlComm = new SqlCommand
         (
           "SET IDENTITY_INSERT Agent ON " +
           "INSERT INTO Agent (UniqueAgentId, EntityType, FirstName, LastName, NameSuffix, CorporateName, LastChangeOperator, LastChangeDate, ControlId) " +
           "VALUES (@agentID, @entityType, @fName, @lName, @suffix, @corporateName, @lastChangeOperator, @lastChangeDate, @controlID)" +
           "SET IDENTITY_INSERT Agent OFF",
            sqlConn//, sqlTrans
         );

         sqlTrans = sqlConn.BeginTransaction("SqlAgentTableUpdates");
         sqlComm.Parameters.Add(agentID);
         sqlComm.Parameters.Add(lastChangeOperator);
         sqlComm.Parameters.Add(lastChangeDate);
         sqlComm.Parameters.Add(controlId);
         sqlComm.Parameters.Add(entityType);
         sqlComm.Parameters.Add(fName);
         sqlComm.Parameters.Add(lName);
         sqlComm.Parameters.Add(suffix);
         sqlComm.Parameters.Add(corporateName);
         sqlComm.Transaction = sqlTrans;
         sqlComm.ExecuteNonQuery();

         //Set variables for AgentIdentification table
         SqlParameter taxIdType = new SqlParameter("taxIdType", "S");//Hard-coded value for testing - CHANGE LATER
         SqlParameter agentTaxId = new SqlParameter("@agentTaxId", "999999999");//Hard-coded value for testing - CHANGE LATER

         //Insert record into AgentIdentification table
         sqlConn = (SqlConnection)cm.AcquireConnection(Dts.Transaction);
         sqlComm = new SqlCommand
         (
           "INSERT INTO AgentIdentification (UniqueAgentId, TaxIdType, AgentTaxId, LastChangeOperator, LastChangeDate, ControlId) " +
           "VALUES (@agentID, @taxIdType, @agentTaxId, @lastChangeOperator, @lastChangeDate, @controlId)",
            sqlConn//, sqlTrans
         );

         sqlComm.Parameters.Add(taxIdType);
         sqlComm.Parameters.Add(agentTaxId);
         sqlComm.Transaction = sqlTrans;
         sqlComm.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
       sqlTrans.Rollback();
       cm.ReleaseConnection(sqlConn);
    }
    finally
    {
       sqlTrans.Commit();
       cm.ReleaseConnection(sqlConn);
    }
```

**EDIT**

I was able to make this transaction work by eliminating the second connection. However, both queries use a couple of the same variables (SqlParameters). I was forced to duplicate these in order for this to run without errors. Is there a way for them to share the variables so I do not have to waste space re-creating them?

Comment: I was curious, what compelled you to write your own insert logic over using the existing SSIS OLE/ADO destinations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem might be with the connection, or when you set the command to a new command for the second insert, you can use two different commands with the same connection or reuse one command just changing the CommandText property.

Hope this helps... [Using SqlTransaction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqltransaction.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

A transaction cannot span multiple connections... does `cm.AcquireConnection` return a new connection each time?  If so, try using the same connection for both commands.

Answer (score 0):

use transactionscope

```
using(TransactionScope ts = new TransactionScope())
{

        using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(myconnstring)
        {
            conn.Open();
    //call first executenonquery
    //call second executenonquery
            ts.Complete();
            conn.Close();
        }
}
```

Comment: TransactionScope has less than optimal performance... it can also be problematic with certain firewall configurations.  Other options can be a better fit.